# Javascript profanity match NOT replace

Tags: javascript, profanity

I am building a very basic profanity filter that I only want to apply on **some fields** on my application (fullName, userDescription) on the **serverside**.

Does anyone have experience with a profanity filter in production? I only want it to:

```
'ass hello' <- match
'asster' <- NOT match
```

Below is my current code but it returns true and false on **in succession** for some reason.

```
var badWords = [ 'ass', 'whore', 'slut' ]
  , check = new Regexp(badWords.join('|'), 'gi');

function filterString(string) {
  return check.test(string);
}

filterString('ass'); // Returns true / false in succession.
```

How can I fix this "in succession" bug?

Comment: What happens if the word is say "asshole"?

Comment: nothing, because it is not in the list, if I would add it to the list: var badWords = [ 'asswhole', 'ass', 'whore', 'slut' ]; then it would match indead, and the user will get a warning.

Comment: I've created a jQuery filter that does what you're looking for. Find it here: http://profanityfilter.chaseflorell.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) sets the [`lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of the regex to the current matched position, so that further invocations will match further occurrences (if there were any).

```
check.lastIndex // 0 (init)
filterString('ass'); // true
check.lastIndex // 3
filterString('ass'); // false
check.lastIndex // now 0 again
```

So, you will need to reset it manually in your `filterString` function if you don't recreate the RegExp each time:

```
function filterString(string) {
    check.lastIndex = 0;
    return check.test(string);
}
```

Btw, to match only full words (like "ass", but not "asster"), you should wrap your matches in word boundaries like WTK suggested, i.e.

```
var check = new Regexp("\\b(?:"+badWords.join('|')+")\\b", 'gi');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are matching via a substring comparison. Your Regex needs to be modified to match for whole words instead

Answer (score 1):

How about with fixed regexp:

```
check = new Regexp('(^|\b)'+badWords.join('|')+'($|\b)', 'gi');

check.test('ass') // true
check.test('suckass') // false
check.test('mass of whore') // true
check.test('massive') // false
check.test('slut is massive') // true
```

I'm using `\b` match here to match for word boundry (and start or end of whole string).